# Lifecycle hook which follows all the classes instantiations

Tags: angular

Imagine the following **component tree** in Angular 4:

```
                  A
                 / \ 
                B   D
               /     \
              C       E
```

I want to run something `inside E` but I want to be sure the `constructor of C` has been initialized. Can `ngAfterViewInit()` **on E** guarantee that? Is it sure for all 5 constructors to having been initialized prior to `ngAfterViewInit`? Once again, I want something inside E which will guarantee the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such guarantee. Even if C has been already instantiated at the moment when E `ngAfterViewInit` was triggered, this may be not for other conditions, e.g. when components are compiled asynchronously. Relying on this precedence is wrong move here.

If the objective is to send a message from E to C or vice versa, the communication should be performed either through common parent (A) property or a service that belongs to parent injector or higher.

Considering that the order in which an observable will be subscribed and emit the value is undetermined, it should be replayable, e.g. `ReplaySubject`. In this case a subscriber will receive a message any way.

Considering that a subject was defined as

```
fooSubject = ReplaySubject(1)
```

in component A and a reference to it was passed to C and E, component E  sends a message as `fooSubject.next(...)`, and component C receives it as `fooSubject.subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Why you can't use service? In constructor of C you can for example set flag of that service to true. In E component you can do simple condition if value of flag in service is true it call function.

Comment: I want to transmit events through Observables. I do not want the solution you suggest

Comment: You didn't mention how so I suggested you simple solution. Communication using observables: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the constructor is the first lifecycle method to run, so there shouldn't be a problem. For example, you could easily test this with console.log in the constructor and ngOnInit of the different components.

Edit: This would obviously only be true if the components aren't initialized conditionally or asynchronously.